# ASP.Net Identity application is looking for membership tables

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I am working on application using Identity 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.5.1. It is giving me error Invalid object name [dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions].

Why is it even looking for membership tables?

I searched the net and most says that I should use \v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe to Configure SQL server application services and when I do that it creates all new stored procedures and tables being used for simple membership.

I strictly want to use Identity 2.0 and do not want to use membership. I have AspNetUsers , AspNetRoles tables in my database but it is expecting other tables like 'dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions'.

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed down to the code that is causing it to look for "aspnet_SchemaVersions" table. In _layout.cshtml page, I was trying to show UserAdmin page if the user is an Admin. That was causing the project to look for Membership related tables. I have commented this and droped the membership related tables and it is working fine. Only issue is that now even Admin cannot see UserAdmin Page.
This is what I commented in _layout.cshtml

@

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))  {

@Html.ActionLink("RolesAdmin", "Index", "RolesAdmin")

@Html.ActionLink("UsersAdmin", "Index", "UsersAdmin")

}

@